# An unexpected error (2063) occurs when I connect to my queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm looking to setup a Queue Manager Using WebSphere MQ V7 MQ Explorer.
After Creating my Queue Manager, normally I expect that some sub directories are automatically generated under it, "Queues", "Topics", "Channels" .. as illustrated in the photo below.

[image: normal case]

In my case, no sub directories are generated, as illustrated below in the second snapshot.
**PS**: the status of my Queue manager is : **Running but disconnected** from WebSphere MQ Explorer.

[image: my case]

When I right-click on the QMgr Name and choose Connect, I get "An unexpected error (2063) has occurred (AMQ4999)"

Could you advise please about a possible cause of this behavior ?

Comment: `Right-click QMGR Name -> Connect`. Have you tried this?

Comment: i got the following error : "An unexpected error(2063) has occured (AMQ 49999)"

Comment: 2063 is a security error. Are you running MQ explorer as a user who is part of either the 'mqm' group or the 'Administrator' group?

Comment: Please look in the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG and show the error that is written there at the time you attempt to connect to the queue manager. There are a number of reasons why you might be given a 2063 error and without the information from the queue manager error log any answer given would only be a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Administrative tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service -> Properties -> ***add your user here***

Same problem with MQ v9 and i solved it this way.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to control panel – Administrative tools
   [image]
2. Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools
3. Local 
   [image]
4. Inside Local Security Policy
   [image]
   [image]
5. Enter your domain user name then click check names – finalize by clicking ok. Then apply.
   [image]
6. Now the domain user can log on as a service – Now open the services running on your machine.
   [image]
7. Double click on the MQ service – then go  on log on tab
   [image]

Then apply click okay button – from the restart your machine for the changes to take effect
Finally open WebSphere MQ Explorer as admin - queue manager should be able to connect

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with MQ 9.0 installed on Windows 10 EE.

(Run as Administrator) **secpol.msc /s** 
(open) **Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Log on as a service**
then add your User. Same user should be used for "IBM MQ (Installation1)" (Properties> Log On), installation default (when you do not setup the Domain Policy during installation) is MUSR_MQADMIN.

(Maybe you can try to run "MQ Explorer" as MUSR_MQADMIN user, but it's password is automatically generated during the installation. It's possible to change it, but it doesn't seem to be a safer against the using local account to run the MQ service)