# IBM Websphere 8.5 - Consume messages from a Local Queue

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-8

I have my application running on WAS 8.5 which consumes messages from IBM MQ. However, I want to test some functionality of my application by posting some messages to the MQ. I am trying to consume messages by creating a queue in my local setup & configuring the queue in WAS 8.5.

I have installed IBM MQ Explorer 9 in my system and created a queue manager & a queue as well. Attached below screenshot from MQ Explorer.
[image]

I am trying to have the TEST_QM & TEST_Q1 configured in the WAS 8.5 admin console under Queue connection factories.

[image]

Queue Manager Configuration in WAS

[image]

Host & port configuration in WAS

[image]

However, when I try the connection test in WAS, it returns me the below error.

[image]

I am a newbie to WAS, MQ & IBM world. Kindly guide as to where am I going wrong & how can my application consume messages from local queue?

Thank you!

Comment: Look in the file `AMQERR01.LOG` in the MQ data path due the queue manager.   It should have more details on the failure.

Comment: Also this question may help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181936/an-unexpected-error-2063-occurs-when-i-connect-to-my-queue-manager

Comment: Your screenshot shows an empty value for Server connection channel in Step 2.2. Did you fill in your connection channel after you took the screenshot? The default is SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN, are you intending to use that channel?

Comment: @lwestby I tried adding the default channel name & tried testing the connection. I got an error stating host not available.

Comment: In MQ explorer, what channels do you have listed? SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN is just a hardcoded WAS default, it may not exist or may not allow connections. There should be one for applications like APP.DEV.SVRCONN or something that you need to put in that field.